# List of all dangerous character combinations for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

There are many questions for how to avoid triggering "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error messages which include turning off validation (scary!). I still need to validate the page, so I need a list of special characters that trigger this so that I can provide a user experience better than an error 500 page by replacing the characters before it hits the server. That way if someone turns off javascript for malicious reasons, the server still prevents the characters.

So far as I know the only things that trigger this is < with a non-space character following, and &#. Where can I get a list of all the characters that will trigger this error?

Comment: If you know your code is safe and has no HTML injection, SQL injection and the like, set `ValidateRequest="false"` or `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]` instead of adding more and more code. KISS: keep it simple stupid.

Comment: @ThomasWeller As per the post: "I still need to validate the page"; so is there a list of character combinations that trigger this message anywhere?

Comment: Since it's a built in part of the framework I'm not sure a list will exist. Microsoft doesn't describe the exact nature of the validation in their docs. It'll be a lot easier to just html encode the entire content before sending it to the server, if that'll work for you.

Comment: on the contrary - I would expect a list some place. I have a text box with comments - our site is generating errors as a result - until such time we can re-deploy that application, we might put some text or warnings to note this issue. It not all that practical to just out of the blue wholesale introduce code into 50+ web pages that need to deal with this issue.

Comment: Maybe there's something in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/videos/) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/zdh19h94(v=vs.90)#guard-against-malicious-user-input).